# How to fuse these two javascript files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

I have a javascript file that is loading up the google charts API and drawing a graph, and another javascript file that handles an html form on the page. I'd like to fuse these two together, as the form will be providing the graph with data. However, when I try to put there google charts js file (`graph.js`), it refuses to load the graph. I've tried putting it in several locations, but it only loads if the `graph.js` is a separate js file that is linked within the html document. Can someone tell me how I can properly combine these two files:

CostComparer.js (the form handler):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //variable setup
    var wifi;
    var firewall;
    var backup;
    var vpn; 
    var install; 
    var result;

    $('#submit').click(function(){ 
        $("#chart_div").show('slow'); 
        $("#table_div").show('slow'); 

        wifi = $('input[name=wifiPrice]').val(); 
        firewall = $('input[name=firewallPrice]').val(); 
        backup = $('input[name=backupPrice]').val(); 
        vpn = $('input[name=vpnPrice]').val(); 
        install = $('input[name=installPrice]').val(); 

        result = parseInt(wifi) + parseInt(firewall) + parseInt(backup) + parseInt(vpn) + parseInt(install); 

        var resultbox = $('#result'); 
        var cccontainer = $('#cccontainer'); 


        if(resultbox.height() < 10){
            cccontainer.hide('slow').delay(500); 
            cccontainer.show('slow'); 
            setTimeout(function() {
                resultbox.append('<h1>You Paid: <br />$' + result + '</h1>')
            }, 500);
        } else {
            resultbox.empty()
            cccontainer.hide('slow').delay(500); 
            cccontainer.show('slow'); 
            setTimeout(function() {
                resultbox.append('<h1>You Paid: <br />$' + result + '</h1>')
            }, 500);
        }

    });
});
```

and graph.js:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


var competitorCost = function(time){
    return 3000 + (time * 300)
};

var ourCost = function(time){
    return 1000 + (time * 50); 
};

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Months', 'Entreda', 'Competitors'],
        ['0', ourCost(0), competitorCost(0)],
        ['6', ourCost(6), competitorCost(6)],
        ['12', ourCost(12), competitorCost(12)],
        ['18', ourCost(18), competitorCost(18)],
        ['24', ourCost(24), competitorCost(24)]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Entreda vs Competitor Costs',
        width: 445,
        height: 250,
        pointSize: 5
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with my compiler it seems. It worked after appending `graph.js` to the bottom outside of `$document.ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     //variable setup
    var wifi;
    var firewall;
    var backup;
    var vpn; 
    var install; 
    var result;

    $('#submit').click(function(){ 
        $("#chart_div").show('slow'); 
        $("#table_div").show('slow'); 

        wifi = $('input[name=wifiPrice]').val(); 
        firewall = $('input[name=firewallPrice]').val(); 
        backup = $('input[name=backupPrice]').val(); 
        vpn = $('input[name=vpnPrice]').val(); 
        install = $('input[name=installPrice]').val(); 

        result = parseInt(wifi) + parseInt(firewall) + parseInt(backup) + parseInt(vpn) + parseInt(install); 

        var resultbox = $('#result'); 
        var cccontainer = $('#cccontainer'); 


        if(resultbox.height() < 10){
            cccontainer.hide('slow').delay(500); 
            cccontainer.show('slow'); 
            setTimeout(function() {
                resultbox.append('<h1>You Paid: <br />$' + result + '</h1>')
            }, 500);
        } else {
            resultbox.empty()
            cccontainer.hide('slow').delay(500); 
            cccontainer.show('slow'); 
            setTimeout(function() {
                resultbox.append('<h1>You Paid: <br />$' + result + '</h1>')
            }, 500);
        }

    });
}); 

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


var competitorCost = function(time){
    return 3000 + (time * 300)
};

var ourCost = function(time){
    return 1000 + (time * 50); 
};

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Months', 'Entreda', 'Competitors'],
        ['0', ourCost(0), competitorCost(0)],
        ['6', ourCost(6), competitorCost(6)],
        ['12', ourCost(12), competitorCost(12)],
        ['18', ourCost(18), competitorCost(18)],
        ['24', ourCost(24), competitorCost(24)]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Entreda vs Competitor Costs Over Time',
        width: 480,
        height: 270,
        pointSize: 5
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```